# Jenkins - MSBuild Web Deploy creating zip instead of deploying

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, msbuild, jenkins, webdeploy

I am having an issue with getting Jenkins to use MSBuild correctly and deploy my built website to the web server.

I have thus far created the web site in Visual Studio 2012 and have used the wizard within to create a publishing profile that will successfully publish to my web server. I have then used the command line version of MSBuild on the same PC to test that the command line arguments work correctly...they do! From this I have then added a build step into Jenkins for MSBuild pointing to the same .sln file and using the same arguments but for some reason it doesn't do a web deploy as expected, it just creates a zip file. I cannot see anything that tells it that it should package it like this and am going a little mad.

The publishing profile that VS created (and I am using) is below:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>http://10.215.134.184/msdeployagentservice</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>Default Web Site/mvcCPE</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>RemoteAgent</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>Administrator</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="">
        <ObjectGroup Name="DefaultConnection" Order="1" Enabled="False">
          <Destination Path="" />
          <Object Type="DbDacFx">
            <PreSource Path="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mvcCPE-20130228154150;Integrated Security=True" includeData="False" />
            <Source Path="$(IntermediateOutputPath)AutoScripts\DefaultConnection_IncrementalSchemaOnly.dacpac" dacpacAction="Deploy" />
          </Object>
          <UpdateFrom Type="Web.Config">
            <Source MatchValue="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-mvcCPE-20130228154150;Integrated Security=SSPI" MatchAttributes="$(UpdateFromConnectionStringAttributes)" />
          </UpdateFrom>
        </ObjectGroup>
      </Objects>
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <MSDeployParameterValue Include="$(DeployParameterPrefix)DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

On the command line I am using the following command:

```
msbuild mvcCPE.sln /property:Configuration=Release /property:DeployOnBuild=True /property:PublishProfile=mvcCPE.pubxml /property:Password=xxxxxx
```

And in Jenkins I have the following:

```
MSBuild Version: v4.0.30319
MSBuild Build File: C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\CPE2\workspace\mvcCPE.sln
Command Line Arguments: /property:Configuration=Release /property:DeployOnBuild=True /property:PublishProfile=mvcCPE.pubxml /property:Password=nimdasys
```

As far as I can understand from all this Jenkins should be building and deploying my site to the server but it's not. Any help is greatly appreciated (I am fairly new to Jenkins and VS).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As it turns out a bit more research provided the last hints of how to fix this.

After a bit more searching this morning I found the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886134/what-do-i-need-to-setup-a-jenkins-build-server-that-can-build-asp-net-projects-w) which was talking about building projects on Jenkins without VS. Following the suggestion from the answer there I copied the folder and files from `C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0` on my development PC to the same place on my build PC and ran the build again with an additional switch `/property:VisualStudioVersion=11.0`. This resulted in me getting the error:

```
C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(3676,5): error : Package/Publish task Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.IsCleanMSDeployPackageNeeded failed to load Web Deploy assemblies. Microsoft Web Deploy is not correctly installed on this machine. Microsoft Web Deploy v3 or higher is recommended. [C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\Call_Plan_Editor_2\workspace\mvcCPE\mvcCPE.csproj]
```

So as it turns out I didn't actually have the Web Deploy assemblies loaded on the build server at all (that's what you get when you let someone else set it up with 'everything' you need!) So I downloaded and installed Web Deploy V3 from Microsoft and, after a couple more tweaks, it now builds and deploys correctly.

Hopefully nobody else is as slow as me to miss such things in the first place but I wanted to answer my own question as I hate finding posts that just say "OK, I fixed it" without an explnation.

Answer (score 1):

Have to install Web Deploy on the client side also. The machine, where you are deploying from.