# Jenkins Build Error - MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist

Tags: .net, svn, jenkins, msbuild, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to create a Jenkins job that will build my .NET web application from an SVN repository that I manage with VisualSVN.

I have added the URL of the project folder in the repository trunk folder to the Jenkins job and when I execute the job it runs fine with no errors.

[image: SVN screenshot]

I then go onto the build step using "Build a Visual Studio Project or Solution using MSBuild", where I enter the full url of the .sln file.

[image: MSBuild Screenshot]

I have configured MSBuild as below and using 4.0 as this is what my application is built in.

[image: MSBuild Settings]

**Extract from .csProj file:**

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

When I run the job it fails with the following error

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
```

[image: MSB1009 screenshot]

But when I click the link in the screenshot above it opens the file in a browser window?

Any ideas are greatly appreciated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use the remote URL but the local path. 
I guess it will be something like:

```
.\Hubble\hubble.sln
```

The plugin will work inside the working directory, which can be found on your build machine at:

```
<JENKINS_DIR>\jobs\<JOB NAME>\workspace
```

Comment: That fixed it for this problem thanks! But I did get a "Microsoft.WebApplication.targets not found error" afterwards. This is due to the server running Jenkins not having Visual Studio installed. Solution found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16886134/what-do-i-need-to-setup-a-jenkins-build-server-that-can-build-asp-net-projects-w

Answer (score 3):

You are checking out the code! You will need to specify the **local** path to the solution. meaning, something like $WORKSPACE/Path/To/sln.file

Good luck

Comment: Also, to state the obvious, ensure correct subdirectory in path is used.

Answer (score 1):

For me it was an issue with Authorization to jenkins as it wasn't able to read/write that file as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/574694/msbuild-error-msb1009-project-file-does-not-exist.html)
Fix:

- Go into Services -> jenkins -> Properties -> Log on
- Change to "This Account" and set your system username password